# want two image side by side with different hyperlink html

Tags: html

I want text on the right side and pics on the left side with a selection of different pic of the product picture on left with one main picture and other thumbnails to select the different angles of the product. 2nd main problem is shared and private checked boxes are besides adult and children selection I want them in the next line below adult and children line

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
          @media (max-width: 640px) {
            .banner {
              flex-direction: column;
            }
          }
  
          body {
              margin: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
              min-height: 100vh;
              min-width: 100vw;
          }
  
          .banner {
              width: 100vw;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: space-around;
          }
  
          .col-2 {
              margin: 2%;
              display: flex;
              justify-content: center;
              align-items: center;
          }
          .clm img {
              width: 100%;
          }

          .counter1 {
                float: left;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }

            .counter2 {
                float: left;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                padding-left: 15px;
            }
            .clm {
                width: 690px;
                padding-left: 20px;
            }

          .up, .down {
                display: inline-block;
                color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
                font-size: 25px;
                margin: 1px 1px;
                cursor: pointer;
                width: 15px;
                line-height: 14px;
                height: 16px;
                text-align: center;
                font-weight: bold;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                user-select: none;
            }
            .up:hover, .down:hover {
                
                color: #fd0b3f;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .adults {
                padding-right: 5px;
            }

            .children {
                padding-right: 5px;
            }

            input {
                appearance: none;
                height: 21px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 42px;
                line-height: 24px;
                font-size: 15px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                
            }
            .container {
                float: left;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
            }
            input[type="radio"]{
                display: none;
            }
            label[for=private] {
                position: relative;
                color: orangered;
                font-size: 30px;
                border: 2px solid orangered;
                border-radius: 5px;
                align-items: left;
                display: flex;
                cursor: pointer;
                margin-right: 10px;
            }
            label[for=shared] {
                position: relative;
                color: orangered;
                font-size: 30px;
                border: 2px solid orangered;
                border-radius: 5px;
                align-items: left;
                display: flex;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            input[type="radio"]:checked + label{
                background-color: orangered;
                color: white;
            }
            input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before{
                height: 16px;
                width: 16px;
                border: 10px solid white;
                background-color: orangered;
            }
        
        
           
      </style>
            <script>

                function increaseCount(e, el) {
                    var input = el.previousElementSibling;
                    var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
                    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                    value++;
                    input.value = value;
                }
                function decreaseCount(e, el) {
                    var input = el.nextElementSibling;
                    var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
                    if (value > 1) {
                        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                        value--;
                        input.value = value;
                    }
                }
                function decreaseCount2(e, el) {
                    var input = el.nextElementSibling;
                    var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
                    if (value > 0) {
                        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
                        value--;
                        input.value = value;
                    }
                }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="clm">
                <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="clm">
                <p>Home / Morning Safari</p>
                <h1>Morning Safari</h1>
                <h4> <label> Total:</label><label class="total Price"></label> </h4>
                <div class="counter1">
                    <Label class="Adults">Adults</Label>
                    <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount(event, this)'>-</div>
                    <input type='text' value='1' readonly>
                    <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
                </div>
                <div class="counter2">
                    <Label class="Children">Children</Label>
                    <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount2(event, this)'>-</div>
                    <input type='text' value='0' readonly>
                    <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
                
                </div><br>
                <div class="container">
                    <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="private" checked="checked">
                    <label for="private">Private</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="shared">
                    <label for="shared">Shared</label>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `<a></a>` tags to be wrapped around the elements you want to create hyperlink out of. So in this case the images should be wrapped in the `a` tags.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
      @media (max-width: 640px) {
        .banner {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        min-height: 100vh;
        min-width: 100vw;
      }

      .banner {
        width: 100vw;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }

      .clm {
        margin: 2%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .clm img {
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="clm">
        <a href="https://bigdunestours.com/desert-safari" target="_blank">
          <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" alt="Picture1" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="clm">
        <a href="https://google.com" target="_self">
          <img src="https://skylandtourism.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/Morning-Safari.jpg" alt="Picture2" />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  <body>
<html>
```

Comment: thanks, buddy issue is solved now got one new issue, actually, I am building a website from GoDaddy half of which is pre built, only some parts need codings like entering this pic and all. so my problem is pic show perfect on pc as I want but it doesn't show on mobile it looks quite small so what can be the coding for that if you can help it will save me time

Comment: @MMunir.Asif I have edited the answer to make it responsive to smaller screen. Basically on smaller screen the images should appear vertically aligned and on larger screens, images will appear side by side. Look for `@media` rules online to make your html code responsive to different screen sizes.

Comment: you are a lifesaver, god bless you with happiness in your life.